# Is this a good way to reference Thinktecture DLLs from a strongly-named .NET DLL?

Tags: identityserver4

PROBLEM:

I am trying to help a co-worker who wants to reference `Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client.Net45.dll` from a VB.NET DLL –- call it `MyVBNet.dll` -- that is strongly-named.  When we run an executable that references `MyVBNet.dll`, `MyVBNet.dll’s` attempt to instantiate a `Thinktecture` object results in the following exception:

```
 FileLoadException was unhandled by user code

 An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in MyVBNet.dll but was not handled in user code 

 Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client.Net45, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)
```

Here is code that I added to the constructor of an object in MyVBNet.dll to reproduce the exception above:

```
 Dim lobjURI = New Uri("http://localhost:4200/")
 Dim lobjOAuth2Client = New Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client.OAuth2Client(lobjURI)
```

POTENTIAL WORKAROUND:

I tried to work around the problem as follows and afterward was able to instantiate a Thinktecture OAuth2Client object in MyVBNet.dll on a Windows 10 computer.  However, I do not know whether this is a good approach.

[1] Find a Developer Command Prompt in the Start menu and do "[right click] > Run as administrator" on it.

[2] In the resulting window, if you do not already have a SNK file with a strong name key, key in something similar to the following to create an SNK file, keyPair2.snk in the example:

```
 sn -k keyPair2.snk
```

[3] Copy a Thinktecture DLL to a directory, cd the Developer Command Prompt window to that directory, and key in the following, where Thinktecture.IdentityServer3.dll is an example of a Thinktecture DLL:

```
 ildasm Thinktecture.IdentityServer3.dll /output:Thinktecture.IdentityServer3.il

 move Thinktecture.IdentityServer3.dll Thinktecture.IdentityServer3.dll_Original

 ilasm Thinktecture.IdentityServer3.il /dll /res:Thinktecture.IdentityServer3.res /key=keyPair2.snk

 gacutil /i Thinktecture.IdentityServer3.dll
```

[4] In Visual Studio, remove your current references to Thinktecture DLLs and replace them by doing "[right click] > Add Reference... > Browse..." on the References node in the Solution Explorer for the assembly to which you wish to add a reference.  Then select the DLL that you want under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL.

Comment: first of all, do you (or your co-worker) really need that legacy OAuth2Client? why not to use up to date `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect` together with `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect` and all the related stuff? You added the *identityserver4* tag, so most likely that is your IdP. And it is an implementation of OpenIdConnect protocol, not only OAuth2.0

Comment: d_f, thanks for the comments.  I am not sure which parts of Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client.Net45 my co-worker, who is in a different time zone, is using.  I instantiated OAuth2Client only to reproduce the "A strongly-named assembly is required." exception.

Comment: The co-worker reported that calling _anything_ from Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client.Net45, resulted in the "A strongly-named assembly is required." exception.  Therefore, I picked a class more-or-less at random from the DLL to instantiate and reproduced the problem.  The potential workaround that I describe above allowed me to instantiate the class.  I asked this question on StackOverflow in case anyone had advice on this situation where a strongly-named .NET DLL calls a third-party DLL that lacks a strong name.

Comment: As I said, first try to avoid using deprecated stuff in new development. That is a strong and common rule. There is nothing special in that library, that one can't find in official, signed and supported ones... Nothing, except, probably a convenient wrapper for bearer token validation. But that's the only thing to look for a workaround

Comment: indeed you can grab anything on github and sign with your own signature. how legal it is in which country -- I don't know, I'm not a lawyer. but technically nothing prevents you from doing that. what is definitely legal everywhere is to contact the owner and ask for paid support (signing in your case)